# Spring Dependency Injection into JPA entity listener

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I need to have a Spring dependency injected into a JPA entity listener. I know I can solve this using @Configurable and Spring's AspectJ weaver as javaagent, but this seems like a hacky solution. Is there any other way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you would do such a thing? It sounds like a bad situation

Comment: Downvoted because of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @NicoVanBelle I have a User entity, for which, before storing it, I would like to have the password hashed. The hashing class is a Spring bean, hence I need to have it injected into the entity.

Comment: Sounds like a job for entity listeners

Comment: Does every save require that you hash the password? If not then the case for hashing password on every save seems less than ideal

Comment: Maybe you need just [password encoder](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/#react-and-spring-data-rest-part-5)?..

Comment: @SeanCarroll I'm not hashing on every save, I'm checking if password has been set (eg. it's been updated), and then hashing it if necessary. I went with entity listeners, but the problem is still the same, I have no way to inject the password encoder into them. What I did at least until I find a better solution is I made a BeanUtil class with static application context, and I'm fetching the encoder bean using this class.

Comment: @Cepr0 notice how the password encoder in the example you linked is not actually a bean at all. I wanted it to be a Spring managed bean that I could inject into the entity listener.

Comment: @Krzaku  you should just hash the password in the service. It's simpler and more transparent.

Comment: How many places do you intend to set the password? IMO it seems like you are making this too complicated.

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another trick is to implement an utility class with static method that helps you to use Spring beans everywhere, not only in managed classes:

```java
@Component
public final class BeanUtil {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    private BeanUtil(ApplicationContext context) {
        BeanUtil.context = context;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> clazz) throws BeansException {

        Assert.state(context != null, "Spring context in the BeanUtil is not been initialized yet!");
        return context.getBean(clazz);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Since Hibernate 5.3 [org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.spi.BeanContainer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/resource/beans/container/spi/BeanContainer.html) and Spring 5.1 [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringBeanContainer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/SpringBeanContainer.html) you do not need to extra autowiring effort any more. See details of this feature in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20852

Simply annotate your EntityListener class with @Component, and do any autowiring like so:

```
@Component
public class MyEntityListener{

  private MySpringBean bean;

  @Autowired
  public MyEntityListener(MySpringBean bean){
    this.bean = bean;
  }

  @PrePersist
  public void prePersist(final Object entity) {
    ...
  }

}
```

In Spring Boot the configuration of LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean is done automatically in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.

Outside of Spring Boot, you have to register SpringBeanContainer to Hibernate:

```
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb = ...
 emfb.getJpaPropertyMap().put(AvailableSettings.BEAN_CONTAINER, new SpringBeanContainer(beanFactory));
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I am getting a "The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle " error on application start. Also Intelij is telling me the the listener must have a no Args constructor

Comment: Consider using lazy injection to solve cyclic dependencies. Works for me.

Comment: Thanks @Illia . This is required if any of the injected beans are injecting the entity manager, Note that spring data repositories will inject the entitymanager, so any bean having a repository or a direct entityManager will wire a circle. Also I didn't need as of Spring Boot 2.2.5 the "@Autowired"  above the constructor

Comment: NOT ALWAYS is the configuration of `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` in a spring boot application automatic. In my case I had to do it in my datasource config. I described it in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution in Kotlin (Spring Boot 2.3.9, Hibernate 5.4.29.Final). First part is similar to Matthias' answer. However, the second part was needed even though it's a Spring Boot application.

### Bean declaration

```
@Component
class EntityXyzListener(val mySpringBean: MySpringBean) {

    @PostLoad
    fun afterLoad(entityXyz: EntityXyz) {
        // Injected bean is available here. (In my case the bean is a 
        // domain service that I make available to the entity.)
        entityXyz.mySpringBean= mySpringBean
    }

}
```

### Datasource configuration

I already had this datasource `@Configuration` in my spring boot app. I only had to add the line of code that puts the `BEAN_CONTAINER` property in the `jpaPropertyMap`.

```
@Resource
lateinit var context: AbstractApplicationContext

@Primary
@Bean
@Qualifier("appDatasource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
fun myAppDatasource(): DataSource {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build()
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = ["myAppEntityManagerFactory"])
fun entityManagerFactoryBean(builder: EntityManagerFactoryBuilder): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
    val localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean =
            builder
                    .dataSource(myAppDatasource())
                    .packages("com.mydomain.myapp")
                    .persistenceUnit("myAppPersistenceUnit")
                    .build()
    // the line below was the long-sought solution :^)
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.jpaPropertyMap.put(
            AvailableSettings.BEAN_CONTAINER, SpringBeanContainer(context.beanFactory))
    return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;


public final class AutowireHelper implements ApplicationContextAware {

private static final AutowireHelper INSTANCE = new AutowireHelper();
private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private AutowireHelper() {
}

/**
 * Tries to autowire the specified instance of the class if one of the specified beans which need to be autowired
 * are null.
 *
 * @param classToAutowire        the instance of the class which holds @Autowire annotations
 * @param beansToAutowireInClass the beans which have the @Autowire annotation in the specified {#classToAutowire}
 */
public static void autowire(Object classToAutowire, Object... beansToAutowireInClass) {
    for (Object bean : beansToAutowireInClass) {
        if (bean == null) {
            applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(classToAutowire);
            return;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @return the singleton instance.
 */
public static AutowireHelper getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    AutowireHelper.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}
```

}

and then

```
 @Autowired
SomeService thatToAutowire;

  AutowireHelper.autowire(this, this.thatToAutowire);//this in the method
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending a bit the above responses:
Since Hibernate 5.3 org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.spi.BeanContainer and Spring 5.1. You can use this to post process loaded domain entities for instance. Instead of using the aspect.
See:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/SpringBeanContainer.html

In your config:

```
@Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean customCartEntityManagerFactory(DataSource customCartDataSource, EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        var mf = builder
                .dataSource(customCartDataSource)
                .packages("com.my.domain")
                .build();
        mf.getJpaPropertyMap().put(AvailableSettings.BEAN_CONTAINER, new SpringBeanContainer(beanFactory));
        return mf;
    }
```

In your entity bean:

```
@EntityListeners(MyEntityListener.class)
```

The listener, notice no @Component decoration.

```
@Slf4j
public class MyEntityListener implements BeanFactoryAware, InitializingBean {

    private final BeanConfigurerSupport beanConfigurerSupport = new BeanConfigurerSupport();


    public CustomCartEntityListener() {
        log.info("MyEntityListener created");
    }

    @PostLoad
    public void postLoad(MyEntity entity) {
        beanConfigurerSupport.configureBean(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanConfigurerSupport.setBeanWiringInfoResolver(new AnnotationBeanWiringInfoResolver());
        this.beanConfigurerSupport.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        this.beanConfigurerSupport.afterPropertiesSet();
        log.info("MyEntityListener initialized");
    }

}
```