# Autowired annotation not working with @PostLoad

Tags: java, spring

I want to use it for manipulating data from the repository with catalog service, but Autowired annotation is not injecting dependency.

```
@Service
public class PostEntityListener {
 @PostLoad
 public <T> void onPrePersist(T obj) {
    if (obj != null) {
        String type = obj.getClass().getSimpleName();
        switch (type) {
        case "Order":
            break;
        case "OrderItem":
            try {
                OrderItem orderItem = (OrderItem) obj;
                if (orderItem != null) {
                    catalogService.save(orderItem);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
 }
 @Autowired
 private CatalogService catalogService;

}
```

Here are my `CatalogService` details:

```
public interface CatalogService {

   void save(OrderItem orderItem);

}

@Service
public class CatalogServiceImpl implements CatalogService {

   public void save(OrderItem orderItem) {
      catalogRepository.save(orderItem);
   }

   @Autowired
   private CatalogRepository catalogRepository;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information. How does CatalogService  look like, what is your @Configuration, what component scan is, etc.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What is your spring configuration? Java config, xml, properties? Do you use spring boot auto configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, have in mind that, according to the [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html), you should not mess (either directly or indirectly) with the same persistence context that is invoking your lifecycle method:

> In  general,  the  lifecycle  method  of  a  portable  application  should  not  invoke   EntityManager   or  query  operations,  access  other  entity  instances,  or  modify  relationships  within  the same persistence context [46] . [47]  A lifecycle callback method may modify the non-relationship state of the entity on which it is invoked.

So your call to `catalogService.save(orderItem);` looks suspicious.

Regarding your main question, the problem is that `EntityListener` instances are instantiated by the JPA provider and not by Spring, so you cannot directly use Spring goodies in them. You can implement some workarounds, though, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941717/spring-dependency-injection-into-jpa-entity-listener) for more details, specially Den B's answer looks easily adaptable to your code.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried it , just follow below snippet code.

```
@Component
public class DeptItemTransferBean {

    @Autowired
    private CatalogRepository catalogRepository;

   public void save(OrderItem orderItem) {
     catalogRepository.save(orderItem);
```

Comment: my issue is in PostEntityListener class where I want to inject CatalogService but its always initialize with null.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue with setter-injection. I used the following code to inject dependency:

```
@Autowired
public void setCatalogService(CatalogService catalogService) {
    this.catalogService = catalogService;
}
```

Comment: It is called injection with setter method. This `init(..)` is actually a `setCatalogService(...)`. It would be less confusing if you rename this method.

Comment: sure - @Viacheslav Shalamov